# Question considering iframe/xslt/xml file

Tags: javascript, xml, iframe

How would you be able to make a button (in xslt) that can be placed on a  website (html page). So when clicked (on the button) a iframe appears and displays for example a file of my choosings functions.php or any other html page.

At the moment i have no really a idea in what direction to look.

The idea is just to display some sort of score table(xml).
This file already has layout trough the xslt file.

At the moment everything is for local testing (localhost).

Best regards.

Comment: This isn't an xslt question. No XML document, no desired output.

Comment: Check my old XML/XSLT driven site at http://www.aranedabienesraices.com.ar/fotos.php?codigo=AD020207 . This use an iframe for displaying large image selected from a snapshot gallery